# How can I replace null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like these:

```
// users
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |     avatar     | visibility |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+
| 1  | John   | 344        | er0942334r4... | 1          |
| 2  | Peter  | 65544      | 340ojfc343f... | 0          |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+

// posts
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Also here is my query:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name, u.reputation rep, u.avatar
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = p.author_id AND u.visibility = 1
// please focus on this-> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And here is the **current** result:

```
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |  name  | rep  |     avatar     |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         |        |      |                |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         | John   | 344  | er0942334r4... |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
```

Now I want to set some default values when `visibility <> 1` or `name or rep or avatar is null`. So here is the **expected** result:

```
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |  name  | rep  |     avatar     |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         | NoName | 1    | default        |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         | John   | 344  | er0942334r4... |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I can do that by PHP like this:

```
$name = is_null($result['name'])   ? 'NoName'  : $result['name'];
$name = is_null($result['rep'])    ? 1         : $result['rep'];
$name = is_null($result['avatar']) ? 'default' : $result['avatar'];
```

But I want to know how can I do that by *pure sql*.

Comment: use a case/when as one way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) :

```
SELECT p.*,
       COALESCE(u.name,'NoName') as `name`,
       COALESCE(u.reputation,1) as rep,
       COALESCE(u.avatar,'default') as avatar
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = p.author_id AND u.visibility = 1
```

You can also replace it with [`IFNULL`](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/ifnull.php) . The difference between them is that `COALESCE()` can handle multiple arguments.

Comment: You've used `COALESCE` for each of them separately. Yes that's correct, and you also can use `CASE WHEN` too. But I guess I you can do that by just one condition, because if one of them is null, then all are null.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. Yes you can also use `CASE EXPRESSION` which is a bit less readable. You can't use 1 condition for all the columns, every column is being calculated separately , so you have to put the condition each time. You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` and address the same column each time, but it will still be 3 conditions. @MartinAJ