# How can I make an abbreviation from the number?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current table:

```
// table
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | jack   | 534431     |
| 2  | peter  | 334        |
| 3  | amos   | 1300       |
| 4  | carter | 13490      |
| 5  | basil  | 1351       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I want to change the value of `reputation` column to a number based on kilo. Actually I'm trying to make it shorter. Exactly what stackoverflow does. So the expected output is something like this:

```
// newtable
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | jack   | 534k       |
| 2  | peter  | 334        |
| 3  | amos   | 1.3k       |
| 4  | carter | 13.4k      |
| 5  | basil  | 1.3k       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: use a case/when block

Comment: @Drew [Hah, twice!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292759/how-can-i-replace-null?noredirect=1#comment64002687_38292759)

Comment: You don't do that inside your table, that is extremely unefficient. Instead you store the numerical value and only "translate" it on-the-fly for visualization. There are libraries for that, depending on the scripting language you use to access the data.

Comment: @arkascha I don't want to store them as kilo, I want to convert it when I select the row.

Comment: You have to use a case construct. Doesn't matter if you use a scripting language or sql. You can, however, put that logic into a stored procedure in sql and use it as a function during a `SELECT` query.

Comment: imho this conversion belongs in your presentation layer, not in sql-based data extraction. what kind of language are you writing your presentation layer in?

Comment: @Creos I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat()`, `case`, and some arithmetic:

```
select id, name,
       (case when reputation < 1000 then cast(reputation as char)
             when reputation < 1000000 then concat(cast(floor(reputation/1000) as char), 'k')
             when reputation < 1000000000 then concat(cast(floor(reputation/1000000) as char), 'M')
             else 'Wow!!!'
        end) as reputation
. . .
```

EDIT:

To get the decimal point for some values:

```
select id, name,
       (case when reputation < 1000 then format(reputation, 0)
             when reputation < 100000 then concat(format(reputation/1000, 2), 'k')
             when reputation < 1000000 then concat(format(reputation/1000, 0), 'k')
             when reputation < 100000000 then concat(format(reputation/1000000, 1), 'M')
             when reputation < 1000000000 then concat(format(reputation/1000000, 0), 'M')
             else 'Wow!!!'
        end) as reputation
. . .
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67634b/19) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Also your solution doesn't support float results like this `1.3k`

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . The answer has been fixed.  I think `format()` is the best function to use.

Answer (score 2):

I can use `CASE WHEN` and `TRAILING` like this:

```
SELECT id, name,
    CASE WHEN value >= 1000 THEN
         CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM SUBSTR(TRUNCATE(number/1000, 1), 1, 4)), 'k')
         ELSE value
    END as reputation
FROM `table`
```